# How does this code stop the parent from collapsing on floating it's children?

Tags: html, css

The code below stops the 'clearfix' parent element from collapsing when both of it's children are floated.

Can anyone tell me how / why it works?

HTML:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div style="float: left;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Div 2</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear: both` - that's about it.

The "old-fashioned" (read: compatible with older browsers) way of doing it is by manually adding an element, say:

```
<br style="clear:both" />
```

to the end of the container. However `:after` lets you do that without having to manually add said element.

In any case, a simpler way is to just apply `overflow:hidden` to the `.clearfix` element instead of hacking around with psuedoelements, but obviously depending on circumstance that may not be ideal.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to adding an explicit block element with `clear: both` at the end:

```
<div>
    <div style="float: left;">Div 1</div>
    <div style="float: left;">Div 2</div>
    <div style="clear: both; height: 0;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>​
```

Basically the [`after` pseudoelement](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoelement-after) introduces an element as a new virtual child of the selected element, with the specified style.

Comment: Clearing div should be *inside* the element - psuedoelements are children of the parent.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Are you sure? My understanding is that `after` introduces a *sibling* of the selected element

Comment: I'm sure. It's the whole reason why you can't have `:after` on things like `<img>` or `<input>`. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/76qmS/)

Answer (score 1):

Adding `.clearfix { overflow:auto }` would also work. While avoid having to use the extra element with a `clear:both`.

It should be noted that `overflow: auto` is a bit susceptible to paddings, which can accidentally generate scroll bars (but you can visually test that)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use the following code to clear elements.
It supports almost every browser on every platform.
You can also use it for e-mail clients when you're designing an HTML e-mail.

Explanation:
"clear:both" does most of the job. It turns off the floating functionality of the HTML element.
The ":after" is a CSS pseudo-element. It adds a "virtual" element at the end your CSS selector. This "virtual" element won't appear in your source code.

```
/**
 * @info Clearfix: clear all the floated elements
 */
.clearfix:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    font-size:0;
    content:" ";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
.clearfix {display:inline-table;}

/**
 * @hack Display the Clearfix as a block element
 * @hackfor Every browser except IE for Macintosh
 */
    /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
    * html .clearfix {height:1%;}
    .clearfix {display:block;}
    /* End hide from IE-mac */
```